# Sqlite: Why does 'select min(time) from asdftable' return a blank row when DB is empty?

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is an oddity.  I have an empty SQLite DB.

When I execute `select min(time) from asdftable` I get a blank row back.  When I execute `select time from asdftable` I get nothing back (which is proper).

Any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aggregate functions all  return something even if nothing is found, simply because they are implicitly grouping all (any) rows in your table to get you an aggregate value.  Take `count` for example:

```
sqlite> create table foo (a int not null);
sqlite> select count(a) from foo;
0
```

`null` is to `min` as `0` is to `count` where no rows are returned.

This can be a useful property.  Consider the following example:

```
sqlite> select ifnull(min(a), "I'm null") from foo;
I'm null
```

If you want to filter this case so no records are returned, you can use a having clause (and make the grouping explicit):

```
sqlite> select min(a) as min_a from foo group by a having min_a not null;
```

Comment: Hmm.  Is there any way to have it not return anything instead of "marking" the null?

Comment: Yes... by using `having`.  See my updated answer for more info.